# how to read messages.properties in Annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I want to use localization to localize the Swagger Documentation. But I can only provide compile time constants to Annotations. So I'm confused how to provide read messages from messages_**.properties and provide it to annotations.

**Message Source**:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomMessageSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return slr;
    }

}
```

Reading messages from messages_**.properties:

```
@Component
public class MessagesByLocaleServiceImpl implements MessagesByLocaleService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String id) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(messageSource.getMessage(id, null, locale));
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm reading messsages in Java Code:

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot"))).build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .tags(new Tag("Netmap Mode Service", messageSource.getMessage(MessageCodes.SWAGGER_WINDOWS_ONLY)));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(messageSource.getMessage(MessageCodes.SWAGGER_TITLE))
                .description(messageSource.getMessage(MessageCodes.SWAGGER_DESCRIPTION))
                .contact(messageSource.getMessage(MessageCodes.SWAGGER_CONTACT)).build();
    }
```

But how can I provide these messages to Swagger Annotations.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Add Netmap mode ", notes = "**I want to read properties here**")
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(value = SwaggerSinglePoint.DESC_MODE_NAME, dataType = CDSwaggerPrimitives.STRING, name = SwaggerSinglePoint.MODE_NAME, paramType = CDSwaggerPrimitives.PARAMA_TYPE_QUERY),
            @ApiImplicitParam(value = SwaggerSinglePoint.DESC_MODE_BUFFER_SIZE, dataType = CDSwaggerPrimitives.INETEGER, name = SwaggerSinglePoint.BUFFER, paramType = CDSwaggerPrimitives.PARAMA_TYPE_QUERY)})
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = CDConstants.JSON_RESPONSE_DATA_FORMAT, consumes = CDConstants.JSON_REQUEST_DATA_FORMAT)
    @SuppressWarnings({ "squid:S3776", "squid:S1319", "unused" })
    public String testController(@RequestBody(required = false) HashMap requestParamMap, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
```

I want to read messages in these annotations. Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to decouple your documentation comments from your code (reading text from external property file rather than ineserting as plain text)

Use the placeholder like so,instead of

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Add Netmap mode " ,...)
```

use

```
@ApiOperation(value = ${message.addNetMode} ,...)
```

Here inside "messages_**.properties" file there should be key-value pair

```
message.addNetMode=Add Netmap mode
```

Also register the property file in your configuration on class level

```
@PropertySource("classpath:messages_**.properties")
```

**Note that values for some annotations might not be supported.Refer docs http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#support-for-documentation-from-property-file-lookup

Comment: But I have so many files messages_en.properties, messages_fr.properties etc. Which file should I load? Is there a way I can load a particular file in classpath basis on any another property in application.properties. For ex. if I have locale=EN in application.properties then I can load messages_en.properties.

Comment: @Abhishek how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get values from `application.properties` by using `SPEL` i.e. `${}`:

> @Annotation(value="${request.reminder.mails.cron.expression}")

Note:- the props name should be complete name from `application.properties`.

Comment: But I want to read from messages_**.properties. And this file is not in my classpath.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to have it in classpath

Comment: But I have so many files messages_en.properties, messages_fr.properties etc. Which file should I load? Is there a way I can load a particular file in classpath basis on any another property in application.properties. For ex. if I have locale=EN in application.properties then I can load messages_en.properties.

Comment: That's a level before to what you asked for. You are talking about changing between loaded files based on locale. This usage is independent of which file you have loaded given the property key is same in those files.

Comment: Hi, It can be used like this
 @Range(min = 0, max = 100 ,message = "{error.messages.weight}")

error.messages.weight comes from message.properties. Following line show us its declaration
error.messages.weight= Weight should be between 0 and 100